Keras siamese model history is empty
I am making a siamese neural network with triplet loss using keras, and have encountered an odd problem. I tried saving my history twice: once in a callback (saved as a dictionary), and once after training with model.fit(), using pickle (saved as a history object). In both instances, the code runs smoothly, but afterwards the saved files are only several hundred bytes and when I plot them with matplotlib, the plot is empty.
Here's the callback I passed to model.fit():
class MetricsCallback(tensorflow.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, train_data, validation_data, embedding_model, folder_path, file_name):
        super(MetricsCallback, self).__init__()
        self.validation_data = validation_data
        self.train_data = train_data
        self.history={}
        self.embedding_model=embedding_model
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.folder_path = folder_path

    def calc_metrics(self ,dataset):
      #for  accuracy
        y_true_acc=[]
        y_pred=[]

        #for auc-roc and eer
        y_true=[]
        y_scores=[]

        for triplet in dataset: #dataset is train_data or validation_data
          anchor, positive, negative = triplet #get the anchor, posotive and negative tensors from each triplet tuple
          a_emb=embedding_model(np.expand_dims(anchor, axis=0)) #get the embeddings for each
          p_emb=embedding_model(np.expand_dims(positive, axis=0))
          n_emb=embedding_model(np.expand_dims(negative, axis=0))

          dist_p = np.linalg.norm(a_emb - p_emb) #calculate distances
          dist_n = np.linalg.norm(a_emb - n_emb)
          #for triplet acc:
          y_true_acc. append(1) #the true label is always 1
          if dist_p +alpha<dist_n : #accurate
            y_pred.append(1)
          else:
            y_pred.append(0)

          #for auc-roc and eer:
          y_true.append(0) #for a-p
          y_true.append(1) #for a-n

          y_scores.append(1-dist_p)#if it's small like we want, it gets a high score
          y_scores.append(dist_n)# if it's big like we want, it gets a high score

        #compute acc:
        accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true_acc, y_pred)
        #compute auc-roc and eer:
        fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_scores)
        auc_roc = auc(fpr, tpr)
        eer = 1 - max(tpr - fpr)

        return accuracy, auc_roc, eer, fpr, tpr

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        # Compute metrics on train data
        loss_train = logs.get('loss')
        accuracy_train , auc_roc_train, eer_train, fpr_train, tpr_train= self.calc_metrics(self.train_data)

        self.history['train_loss'] = loss_train
        self.history['train_accuracy'] = accuracy_train
        self.history['train_auc_roc'] = auc_roc_train
        self.history['train_eer'] = eer_train
        self.history['train_fpr'] = fpr_train
        self.history['train_tpr'] = tpr_train

        # Log the metrics
        print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1} - Train Loss: {loss_train}, Accuracy: {accuracy_train}, AUC-ROC: {auc_roc_train}, EER: {eer_train}')

        # Compute metrics on validation data
        loss_val = logs.get('val_loss')

        accuracy_val, auc_roc_val, eer_val, fpr_val, tpr_val= self.calc_metrics(self.validation_data)

        self.history['val_loss'] = loss_val
        self.history['val_accuracy'] = accuracy_val
        self.history['val_auc_roc'] = auc_roc_val
        self.history['val_eer'] = eer_val
        self.history['val_fpr'] = fpr_val
        self.history['val_tpr'] = tpr_val

        # Log the metrics
        print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1} - Validation Loss: {loss_val},  Accuracy: {accuracy_val}, AUC-ROC: {auc_roc_val}, EER: {eer_val}')

        # Save the metric history to Google Drive
        epoch_number = epoch + 1  # Epoch starts from 0, so we add 1 to get the actual epoch number
        file_name_with_epoch = f"{self.file_name}_epoch_{epoch_number}.pkl"
        file_path = os.path.join(self.folder_path, file_name_with_epoch)
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as file_pi:
            pickle.dump(self.history, file_pi)
        print('saved metrics')

metrics_callback = MetricsCallback(train_set, val_set,simese_model_1,folder_path, file_name)


I tried just saving the history after training like this, but this too is empty:
with open('historyPath', 'wb') as file_pi:
  pickle.dump(history, file_pi)

I suspect this is because I have a custom loss (triplet loss) and custom metrics in the callback. However, this is the very reason I tried saving it in the custom callback.
Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks.

Hi @Rotem Tom,In your custom callback, that saves the metrics for each epoch in the dictionary, 'self. history'. The issue could be there in case, the dictionary is not instantiated logically or, it is being rewritten in every epoch. There are two points that one has to notice to be sure that the history is saved correctly: The metrics of the epoch have to be accumulated, and not replaced.
